# Add multiple rows in Laravel DB Query (for migrating WordPress usermeta table into new Laravel table)

Tags: sql, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I'm migrating Users from WordPress to Laravel. I want to join the users and user_meta tables. Then I will import into a new table.

In my user_meta table I have multiple rows assigned to the user_id. How do I import multiple rows with their own unique identifier.

Eg.

```
umeta_id = 1, user_id = 1, meta_key = first_name, meta_value = Bob
umeta_id = 2, user_id = 1, meta_key = last_name, meta_value = Builder
```

In the above example, I'd like to add first_name and last_name to the query output.

Then import into a new column in the Laravel DB (and stop using the user_meta reference table approach WordPress uses).

Here is my current query code and the output I get:

```
 $wp_users = DB::connection('wordpress_db')
            // ->select(DB::raw('um.meta_value as first_name'))
            ->select('um.meta_value as first_name')
            ->table('wp_users')
            ->leftJoin('wp_usermeta as um', function ($q) {
                $q->on('um.user_id', '=', 'wp_users.id')
                    ->where('um.meta_key', '=', "first_name");
            })
            ->orderBy('wp_users.id');
```

and if i dump the output:

```
  +"ID": 1
  +"user_login": "123"
  +"user_pass": "123"
  +"user_nicename": "123"
  +"user_email": "b@x"
  +"user_url": "https://x"
  +"user_registered": "2016-1-1 13:47:32"
  +"user_activation_key": ""
  +"user_status": 0
  +"display_name": "Bobby Builds"
  +"umeta_id": 222
  +"user_id": 1
  +"meta_key": "first_name"
  +"meta_value": "Bob"
```

Rather than meta_value and meta_key I just want 'first_name' => 'bob' and then also the ability to do this for multiple values in the user_meta reference table

If I was writing RAW sql then I think I would approach this by having a left_join per value I want to get. I would then create an alias like

SELECT um1.meta_value as first_name
SELECT um2.meta_value as last_name

LEFTJOIN wp_usermeta as um1
LEFTJOIN wp_usermeta as um2

I've noodled around without luck - any ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

I've written about some of the processes involved here for further reference: http://raison.co/migrating-wordpress-users-to-laravel/

Comment: One option would be to make 2 db calls (one to `wp_users` and one to `wp_usermeta`) instead of joining the two together. You will then be able to loop through the `wp_usermeta`  data for the user and append it to the results from the `wp_users` table.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Was focused so hard on the join solution didn’t think about that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the end by using select to choose all columns from wp_users and then selectively adding the new joins.

See the code fixed code below:

```
        $wp_users = DB::connection('wp_db')
        ->table('wp_users')
        ->leftJoin('wp_usermeta as um', function ($q) {
            $q->on('um.user_id', '=', 'wp_users.id')
                ->where('um.meta_key', '=', "wbp_user_mob_phone");
        })
        ->leftJoin('wp_usermeta as um2', function ($q) {
            $q->on('um2.user_id', '=', 'wp_users.id')
                ->where('um2.meta_key', '=', "first_name");
        })
        ->select('wp_users.*', 'um.meta_value as wbp_user_mob_phone', 'um2.meta_value as first_name')
        ->orderBy('wp_users.id');
```